# SDL2 - determine point position of a SDL_MultiGestureEvent

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2

Using SDL2 I would like to selectively handle MultiGestureEvents only if the user is performing them over a special viewport. (For example, only handle pinch zoom events in the upper right corner of the screen, which is a separate viewport)

For a PointEvent (touch up/touch down) I am finding the viewport by taking the absolute point position and then factoring in the viewport offsets to determine which viewport the user has selected.

However for multi-touch I'm not sure how I could determine this because there is no point position data associated with the gesture, any thoughts?

https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_MultiGestureEvent

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the normalized center of the gesture and perform a bounding box check based on your target viewport.